# Is this an active or a passive circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, electrical, network

[image]

Is this an active or a passive circuit?

Comment: Homework question, please walk us through your own thoughts on the matter, show why you think its that way, give that level of effort and we can help you arrive at the answer.

Comment: How are the terms **active** and **passive** defined by your instructor?

Comment: @Reroute i think it is an active circuit because even though the two 5v sources cancel each other out their is some voltage shown on the left hand side of the cicuit and current i is also shown flowing from that source so overall i think it is an active circuit because of that voltage source. But people were concluding that this is a passive circuit on another forum so i am confused.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson An element is active if it is giving out some supply/ power .. Passive doesn't provide supply/power .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two 5V sources cancel, lets say you feed in 1V, the right 2 Ohm resistor ends up only seeing a difference of 1V, same if you feed a current in at "I", the offsets do not prevent the current from flowing through this right resistor, so for all purposes you can remove them, they neither affect nor influence the circuit in any way.

This leaves you with 2 resistors in parallel, a passive and linear circuit.

Comment: ok thanks i get it now :)

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvotes. This is, as far as I'm concerned, the right way to characterise it. If you covered the whole thing in a black box, it'd just look like a 1 ohm resistor from outside.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly an active circuit (because of presence of voltage and current sources), and a linear circuit.

It does not matter that some sources seem to cancel. That is part of the solution, not the characterization.

Comment: Yeah that's what i also thought at first .. but majority of people are concluding that, it is a passive circuit .

Comment: @poonam S so what do you think based on all the discussions and your own knowledge? Suppose I change value of one voltage source to 4.9v. Will it suddenly change from passive to active according to what others have written? Or is that property inherent and unchangeable?

Comment: I think i found an answer on quora ... the person wrote this :   " Components incapable of controlling current by means of another electrical signal are called passive devices. Thus  such an circuit will be considered as passive Circuits. Whereas Active elements generate energy. In other words these devices can increase or supply additional energy into the circuit(may or may not be apart from being the main source).Thus In order for a circuit to be properly called electronic, it must contain at least one active device."

Comment: There you are then. It's active linear like I explained.

Comment: Also i don't know how to answer your question really .. but maybe it would turn into an active source if one of the source is changed to 4.9 v ....:/

Comment: I repeat. FORGET the actual values of the elements. Those are only relevant for an actual calculation. But here we are doing a 'classification' based on TYPE of elements in the circuit only. So if energy source is present == then it is an active circuit. End of story.

Comment: Everyone has a different opinion regarding active and passive circuits ..its still kind of unclear to me  :/  .  I'll see maybe in future i will be able to conclude to my own answer :)

Comment: Actually the definitions are very exact.  Read them carefully with understanding, and you will get it. Never mind opinions of unknown people on the web.